# Stacking multiple query output in one sheet

Tags: google-sheets

For my department I made a dynamic and flexible overview sheet for every teacher, showing his of hers tutored students.

In one overview sheet I have made several query's, that gather data form different sources (students and teachers in different years). The query's are in one column, because I want to generate a list per teacher.

But the output the query formula generate, can differ in length (= number of rows it takes = number of students), that's is why I have to allow for a fixed number of rows in the overview sheet.  And that can lead to ugly blank rows in my list.

Is there a way to keep the flexibility (for every teacher has a different number of tutored students), but remove the blank rows?

Answer (score 3):

If any sheet for every teacher has the same number of same columns, then your data is well-structured and you could make single query on them.

```
=query({Sheet1!A1:C;Sheet2!A2:C},"select * where Col1 <> ''")
```

Pay attention on some details:

1. query should take only one row with headers, use `Sheet1!A1:C` with headers and the others `SheetName!A2:C`
2. when query have source, that contains of multiple tables, use `Col1, Col2, Col3..`. instead of column's letters `A, B, C...` It may be even more convenient. This rule also works, when data is imported from another file.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine ranges using `,` for columns and `;` for rows and by wrapping the ranges in `{}`. (You need to add the curlies after indicating you are concatenating ranges)
Assuming in `Sheet1` you aggregate the data from `Sheet2` and `Sheet3`you can use:

```
={QUERY(Sheet2!A2:B, "SELECT A, B WHERE A <> ''");
  QUERY(Sheet3!A2:B, "SELECT A, B WHERE A <> ''")}
```

Where `A` is the student names (or whatever cannot be empty) and `B` something arbitrary like marks. Of course that query can be as complex as you want (probably best to prebuild it and reuse it via reference then).