# Query Subset of two tabs only returns #N/A

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am trying to combine two tabs of data to plan a daily routine. One tab is for recurring tasks and one for adhoc tasks.
The data on the tabs are mostly similar except on Sheet1 Col4 is a day of the week, whereas on Sheet2 Col4 is a date

What I would like is to choose the current day of the week and have the query return all recurring tasks for that day, as well as any adhoc tasks for that specific date

I can return both sets of data individually however I can't get the query to return both subsets together

```
Sheet1 Data
ID,TASK NAME,LOCATION,TASK DAY
REC1,Task 1,Office,Monday
REC2,Task 2,Office,Tuesday
REC3,Task 3,Field,Wednesday
REC4,Task 4,Office,Thursday
REC5,Task 5,Field,Friday
REC6,Task 6,Field,Monday
REC7,Task 7,Field,Tuesday
```

---

```
Sheet2 Data
ID,TASK NAME,LOCATION,TASK DATE
ADH1,AdHoc 1,Office,25/Jun/2019
ADH2,AdHoc 2,Office,26/Jun/2019
ADH3,AdHoc 3,Field,27/Jun/2019
ADH4,AdHoc 4,Office,28/Jun/2019
ADH5,AdHoc 5,Field,29/Jun/2019
ADH6,AdHoc 6,Field,30/Jun/2019
ADH7,AdHoc 7,Field,1/Jul/2019
```

This pulls the data from sheet 1 based on the day of the week in cell J1

```
=query({Sheet1!A:D}, "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col4 = """&J1&""" ",0)
```

This pulls the data from sheet 2 based on `today()`

```
=query({Sheet2!A:D}, "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col4 = date '" & text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd") & "' ",0)
```

Thought this would work but merely returns an empty set

```
=query({Sheet2!A:D;Sheet1!A:D}, "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col4 = date '" & text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd") & "' OR Col4="""&J1&""" and Col1<>'' ",0)
```

When J1 = `Tuesday` and date = `25/Jun/2019` I should get

```
ID,TASK NAME,LOCATION,TASK DAY
ADH1,AdHoc 1,Office,25/Jun/2019
REC2,Task 2,Office,Tuesday
REC7,Task 7,Field,Tuesday
```

but instead, merely get `#N/A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it.
Rather than put the array inside the queries; put the queries inside the array.

---

```
={QUERY(Sheet1!A:D, "SELECT A, B, C, D WHERE D = """&J1&""" ");
  QUERY(Sheet2!A2:D, "SELECT A, B, C, D WHERE D = date '" & text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd") & "'")}
```

---

Credit - [Stacking multiple query output in one sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35819856/1330560):

Answer (score 1):

Might be too late but issue was in date column after converting it to text query works as well :

```
 =query({Sheet2!A:D; Sheet1!A:D}, "select Col2,Col1,Col3,Col4 where (Col4='"&Sheet1!J1&"' OR Col4 = '" & to_text(today()) & "')",0)
```

Comment: This formula is returning a blank cell for me; hover over reveals no comment/warning Thoughts?

Comment: this is my example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16-jnDNvhOPITfUV6R_r_nXzxIIRr80MxJTS-lBlpFSE/edit#gid=1196597643, there is second tab with green cell. Blank cells might be related with current date values or  j1 cell with day of week  or both.

Comment: Most odd, when I use the date format described by the OP (dd/MMM/YYYY), your code doesn't return the date element. But when I use the date format that you used mm/dd/YYYY, your query DOES work.

Comment: it seems my cells with date have 'date' format. But when they contains incorrect   date format  (dd/MMM/YYYY) (culture related settings) google sheet regards them as string and query is not working.

Comment: the main  point is  '=today()'  have to be th same as date into TASK DAY column. Only in this case query  works.I just provide it only for noting why it did not work for PO.

Comment: `isdate` returns "true" on client format and your format, but I think you are right about (culture/local settings). Just for clarification, the actual date format isn't "yyyy-mm-dd" it's just the default formula setting. In any event, I have progressed to get output from your formula, so Okay by me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I guess easiest way it converts today date to the same format as dates in the column with the next expression =text(today(),"dd/mm/yyyy") (for example). Thanks you too. Your post was useful for me too.